# Set more than one variable value in case statement in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
declare @Month int
declare @A int
Declare @B int
Set @Month = 1

SELECT  
CASE   
WHEN @Month=1 THEN @A=11,@B=21
WHEN @Month=2  THEN @A=111,@B=211
ELSE @A=11,@B=13  END
```

I want to set multiple variable base on condition in `SQL`.
How to do that.I am getting error when I doing like this.

Comment: You are trying to use case _statements_, but SQL has just a case _expressions_. Perhaps you can use an IF statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` expression could be like

```
SELECT @A = CASE @Month WHEN 1 THEN 11
                        WHEN 2 THEN 111
                        ELSE 11 END,
       @B= CASE @Month WHEN 1 THEN 21
                       WHEN 2 THEN 211
                       ELSE 13 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [T-SQL's IF statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/else-if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
IF @Month = 1 
    SET @A=11, @B=21
ELSE IF @Month = 2
    SET @A=111, @B=211
ELSE
    SET @A=11, @B=13
```

Or the usually preferred explicit scope:

```
IF @Month = 1
    BEGIN
    SET @A=11, @B=21
    END
ELSE IF @Month = 2
    BEGIN
    SET @A=111, @B=211
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    SET @A=11, @B=13
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table:

```
select @a = coalesce(max(a), 11),
       @b = coalesce(max(b), 13)
from (values (1, 11, 21),
             (2, 111, 211)
     ) v(month, a, b)
where month = @month;
```

I suggest this because listing the values in a `values()` statement seems like a clean way to list all the values.